# Meaning of a locus.

Tags: complex-numbers, locus

what does this locus mean:

$$\Re\left(\frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2}\right)=0$$
I know it is a circle but can anyone tell a geometric approach, just by looking at the equation ?

Comment: Its a Möbius transform of the imaginary axis, so ... Note however that $z_1=z_2$ leads to the empty set

Answer (score 1):

It means $\;\DeclareMathOperator{\arg}{arg} \bigl\lvert\arg(z-z_1) -\arg(z-z_2)\bigr\rvert=\dfrac\pi2$.

Geometrically, if $M, M_1, M_2$ are the affixes of $z, z_1, z_2$, the geometric angle $\; \widehat{M_1MM_2}$ is a right angle. Hence the locus is the circle with diameter $M_1M_2$, deprived from $M_1$ and $M_2$.

Comment: why $$ pi/2$$ ?

Comment: An imaginary number has argument equal to $\pm\dfrac\pi2$.

Comment: then why positive pi/2?

Comment: I took the absolute value of the difference.

Comment: sir i am sorry to disturb you but please can you explain it to me i n a simple language?

Comment: You do not disturb me at all. What the hypothesis say, is the argument of $\dfrac{z-z_1}{z-z_2}=\arg(z-z_1) -\arg(z-z_2)$ is equal to $\pm\dfrac\pi2$. I translated this into a condition the absolute value of $\arg(z-z_1) -\arg(z-z_2)$, to avoid having two cases. Is that clearer?

Comment: okay so it traces the path of a right angle moving accross the half circle. thank you sir.